# Programatically delete "App Settings:Apps you use" from facebook

Tags: java, facebook, testing, acceptance-testing

I want to automate the facebook signup acceptance tests for my Spring MVC webapp. To do this I need to be able to delete the facebook app from the "Apps you use" section of the "App Settings" of a facebook user profile.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use Test users instead. You can create a new one before you test start and then delete it when the test finish. You may even be able to untos the app using the api.

Comment: Do you mean test user on facebook or in my app? I can do it in my app for sure, but then that won't test the full end-to-end process of authorising the app with facebook.